# PHP: getting a space added after month in a date

Tags: php

I've got a form that loops (using while) all the months of the year in a drop-down. The value is the month in digits (m) and the text is the month in words (F). Everything displays correctly, yet when I post the form I'm getting a space after the 2 month digits. I've checked the form via an echo that the month digits are displaying without a trailing space, so it's definitely after posting. I've tried removing the trailing space with both "substr" and "rtrim" - neither remove the trailing space

Form code:

```
<div class="col-4">
  <label for="phaseMonth" class="form-label ps-2 fw-bold">Draw-off Month</label>
    <?php
      $month = strtotime('2022-01-01');
      $end = strtotime('2023-01-01');
      $limonth = date('F', strtotime($row_lqe['drawoffDate']));
    ?>
  <select name="phaseMonth" title="Select a Date" class="form-select border border-secondary" required>
  <option value="">Select a Month</option>
    <?php while ($month < $end) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo date('m', $month), PHP_EOL; ?>"
        <?php if (!(strcmp(date('F', $month), $limonth))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>
        <?php echo date('F', $month), PHP_EOL; ?>
      </option>
      <?php $month = strtotime("+1 month", $month); ?>
    <?php } ?>
  </select>
</div>
```

Post code:

```
$phaseMonth = $_POST['phaseMonth'];
        if (empty($phaseMonth)) {
            $newphaseMonth = "01";
        } else {
            $newphaseMonth = substr($phaseMonth, 0, -1);
        }
$phaseYear = $_POST['phaseYear'];
        if (empty($phaseYear)) {
            $phaseYear = "2022";
        }
        $drawoffDate = $phaseYear . "-" . $newphaseMonth . "-01";

echo "$phaseMonth:$newphaseMonth:$phaseYear:$drawoffDate"; // to show trailing space
```

echo output:

```
11 :11 :2023:2023-11 -01
```

Comment: You could really help yourself by not having to close and open your PHP tags on every single line, you know?

Comment: I need to compile the date in the correct format so that it can be posted into a MySQL DB in the date format of 2022-01-01

Comment: @Martin I prefer doing it that way in a while loop so that I can compose the HTML easier...

Comment: You would compose it even easier with a `sprintf`

Comment: `<option value="<?php echo date('m', $month), PHP_EOL; ?>` -> `<option value="<?php echo date('m', $month); ?>` ?

Comment: why do you use the `PHP_EOL`? the `rtrim` will not get rid of an EOL character

Comment: If I don't put PHP_EOL I get an endless loop for some reason...

Comment: EOL doesn't have anything to do with looping, that can't be the reason

Comment: ok, so I removed the EOL and I'm no longer getting an endless loop, so I probably solved the endless loop the same time I added the EOL. I'll mark this as answered. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You seemed to miss the point about your excessive overuse of `<?php` and `?>` tags; see this example and how much cleaner it is to view and work with:

```
<div class="col-4">
  <label for="phaseMonth" class="form-label ps-2 fw-bold">Draw-off Month</label>
    <?php
      $month = strtotime('2022-01-01');
      $end = strtotime('2023-01-01');
      $limonth = date('F', strtotime($row_lqe['drawoffDate']));
      print "<select name='phaseMonth' title='Select a Date' 
             class='form-select border border-secondary' required>
             <option value=''>Select a Month</option>\n";
      while ($month < $end) { 
         print "<option value='".date('m', $month)."'";
         if (strcmp(date('F', $month), $limonth) === 0) {
            echo "selected='selected'";
         } 
         print ">".date('F', $month)."</option>\n";
         $month = strtotime("+1 month", $month);
      } 
   ?>
  </select>
</div>
```

- Remove your `PHP_EOL` they're worthless here.
- Use single and double quotes to double wrap quote marks rather than escaping quotes.
- Use string concatenation `.` to streamline, as well as removing `?> <?php`
- This is a quick example only and can be further reduced but reduces readability.

Comment: I didn't miss your point, I just didn't agree with it. I'm not saying you're wrong either. I will however look this over and learn from it. Thanks for writing it out for me to see an alternate way...